# Web API 2 - customize endpoint for Token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to do this

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/MyCustomRoutepath/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
    };
```

Not sure how to achieve this. Looks like Web API creates the /token route automatically. I cannot use it due to some legacy reasons. How do i achieve this? Should i create new controller method and action method and do whatever the token endpoint is supposed to do?

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but you can set the `TokenEndpointPath` to custom token route path you want

```cs
// Summary:
//     The request path client applications communicate with directly as part of
//     the OAuth protocol. Must begin with a leading slash, like "/Token". If the
//     client is issued a client_secret, it must be provided to this endpoint.
public PathString TokenEndpointPath { get; set; }
```

While the documentation give `/Token` as an example, you can use any path you want. No need to create you own controller as the owin middleware will handle auth at the path you specify.

```cs
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/MyCustomRoutepath/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Reference: [Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity - Step 9: Add support for OAuth Bearer Tokens Generation](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)